# How to manage colours of monitor?

Tags: 12.04, monitor, intel

When I was on Windows 7 there was a program:  Intel HD Graphics control panel.

My notebook:

- Acer Aspire 5750G
- Integrated  videocard: Intel HD graphics
- discrete video card: Nvidia 630m

How can I manage colours on Ubuntu 12.04?

Going to *System -> Color* doesn't work for me. I cant calibrate my display:

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on what exactly you want to change, to what and perhaps even why, so we can more easily identify what you're actually looking for.

Comment: Under this i mean saturation.